# React-Rails: Use components with translations I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, rails-i18n, react-rails

I have added to my project `react-rails` gem and I want to use for translated components.

I cannot put in the precompiled assets `erb` templates, but still I am trying to create components, make them available in all the project and then use them in some partial with some translation.

**Working Scenario**

```
# app/view/example/_react_component.coffee.erb
DOM = React.DOM

FormInput = React.createClass
  displayName: "FormInput"
  render: ->
    DOM.div
      className: 'row control-group'
      DOM.div
        className: 'form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls'
        DOM.label
          htmlFor: @props.id
          @props.label
        DOM.input
          id: @props.id
          className: 'form-control'
          placeholder: @props.placeholder
          type: @props.type
        DOM.p
          className: 'help-block text-danger'

formInput = React.createFactory(FormInput)

window.ValidationFormInput = React.createClass
  displayName: "ValidationFormInput"

  getInitialState: ->
    { }

  render: ->
    formInput
      id: "<%= t('validation_form.id') %>"
      label: "<%= t('validation_form.label') %>"
      placeholder: "<%= t('validation_form.placeholder') %>"
      type: 'text'

validationFormInput = React.createFactory(ValidationFormInput)

# app/view/example/index.html.erb
<%= react_component('ValidationFormInput', {}, {class: "container"}) %>
```

**Desired Scenario (not working)**

```
# app/assets/javascripts/components/form_input.coffee
DOM = React.DOM

FormInput = React.createClass
  displayName: "FormInput"
  render: ->
    DOM.div
      className: 'row control-group'
      DOM.div
        className: 'form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls'
        DOM.label
          htmlFor: @props.id
          @props.label
        DOM.input
          id: @props.id
          className: 'form-control'
          placeholder: @props.placeholder
          type: @props.type
        DOM.p
          className: 'help-block text-danger'

formInput = React.createFactory(FormInput)

# app/view/example/_react_component.coffee.erb
window.ValidationFormInput = React.createClass
  displayName: "ValidationFormInput"

  getInitialState: ->
    { }

  render: ->
    formInput
      id: "<%= t('validation_form.id') %>"
      label: "<%= t('validation_form.label') %>"
      placeholder: "<%= t('validation_form.placeholder') %>"
      type: 'text'

validationFormInput = React.createFactory(ValidationFormInput)

# app/view/example/index.html.erb
<%= react_component('ValidationFormInput', {}, {class: "container"}) %>
```

I guess that the issue is related to the scope of the definition of my component, but I cannot figure out how to make the component available for any partial.

Thank you in advance

**Edit**

In order to make the translations available, I found the [`gem I18n-js`](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js). After installing, I can easily run a rake task to create a js version of my `config/locales/*` translations

Comment: Note: avoid js.erb and coffee.erb at all cost =) Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question.

There are a few ways to do this.

1- Usually, this is not just a question about how to pass data from Rails to React but rather how to generally pass data to Javascript. You can store the data in a `meta` in the header and access it from Javascript. This way you can still have your JS compressed and fast. (Instead of js.erb etc)

2- Passing all the translations to the react component. Basically, you can pass arguments to the react component, one of which is the translations. If it's a few translations, it's fine but if your list grows, the load would be heavy on your page.

3- Make your own Javascript translator. Here's a CoffeeScript example that I have created; make sure to add it in your assets' list before the other files.
In my code, I'm pulling the locale from `meta` (as you can see in the code). Feel free to edit this.

```
class Translator
  @en = {
    internet_connection_lost: "Your internet connection has been lost"
    attempting_to_reconnect: "Attempting to reconnect!"
    failed_to_reconnect: "Failed to reconnect..."
    connection_success: "Connected"
    reconnecting: "Reconnecting..."
    bid_received: "Bid received. New balance $$bid_balance$$"
  }

  @ar = {
    internet_connection_lost: "لقد فقدت الاتصال بالإنترنت"
    attempting_to_reconnect: "نحاول إعادة الاتصال!"
    failed_to_reconnect: "لم تنجح إعادة الاتصال بالشبكة..."
    connection_success: "متصل بشبكة الإنترنت"
    reconnecting: "إعادة الاتصال جارية..."
    bid_received: "تم تلقي العرض. رصيد جديد $$bid_balance$$"
  }

  @get_translations: (locale) ->
    switch (locale)
      when 'en'
        @en
      when 'ar'
        @ar

  @translate: (val, interpolation) ->
    # get locale from meta
    locale = $("meta[name='locale']").attr("content") || "en"
    translation = Translator.get_translations(locale)[val]

    if interpolation
      console.log "#{JSON.stringify(interpolation)}"

    for k,v of interpolation
      console.log "#{translation} : #{k} : #{v}"
      translation = translation.replace(k, v)

    return translation

window.Translator = Translator
```

And this is how you can use the Translator

```
  message = Translator.translate(
    "bid_received", { "$$bid_balance$$": 10 }
  )
```

Comment: You are welcome; I hope this is what you are looking for :-)

Comment: Actually I was wondering if there is a simple way to write a `Translator` class that takes automatically all the translation in `config/locales/*` ?

Comment: The meta solution can do this. Your translations are just YAML files; all you need to do is have a route that can have that converted to JSON and inject it as a script. My issue with this solution is that it would do this every time and the text is not compressed. Also, you'll have to fix my interpolator though to accept `%something` =)

Comment: For the translations I actually found this [I18n.js gem](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) which does what I was expecting!
Thank you again for your help